# mysql CHECK constraint on multiple columns and values

Tags: mysql, constraints, unique

I tried to find answer but no luck. I need to create constraint on a table A, that when column X value = 'id' and column Y value is already saved. In other words column Y must be unique only when column X='id'. I created function to check if exists and then tried that: "`alter table A add constraint C CHECK(functionName(Y)=0)`" but got

> Error Code: 1901. Function or expression cannot be used in the CHECK
> clause

.

Comment: updated ur question with a similar fiddle hope it helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wish you had a fiddle, try the constrain below on the create or alter table.

Constraint should be:
UNIQUE (Y, (CASE WHEN X = 'idVal' THEN 'idVal' END))

Here is a [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3c10ccf1b76aa0a37f247e9987948484)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9a31eb0f8fc7961d201b2dd747fbb5da adaptable to the OP question.

Comment: Code: alter table cc_fluentform_entry_details add constraint calliduniq UNIQUE (field_value, (CASE WHEN field_name = 'call_id' THEN 'call_id' END));
I am getting: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(CASE WHEN field_name = 'call_id' THEN 'call_id' END))' at line 1

Comment: Mind to  create a fiddle and provide the link ?

Comment: Fiddle works. Mysql does not. Could it be restriction by wordpress?